# Why do I get 401 error on playlist spotify?

Tags: ajax, spotify, playlist

I'm trying to create a playlist on Spotify through the /playlists endpoint of the Spotify Web API. Even though when i try to execute this code I get a error 401 error, according to the Spotify Documentation this is a kind of authorization error, but I can make other requests with token and I've already written the scopes in app.js

```
    function generatePlaylist(access_token) {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists',
          method: "POST",
          data: {"name": "Test for playlist", "description":"test", "public":false},

          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          },

            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Success!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas? Greetings!

Comment: is there any message with the error?

Comment: @HenryWoody I get in Google Chrome developer console a red message **POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists 401** on left side, right side **api.spotify.com/v1/playlists:1** [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N50rxG7WSD9Sz4sP63iRUQLM_tVqfpxf/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Add an `error` callback, similar to your `success` callback and log the body/text of the response